# Tyne and Wear metro: Tynemouth to Airport; only 2 zones?

Tags: uk, public-transport

Zones are an often unfair but nonetheless common way to organise public transport systems.

On the Tyne and Wear Metro I think I've noticed a bit of an oddity in this however.

[Tyne and Wear Metro map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OL6df.jpg)

If I was to start on the coast, say Tynemouth, then would a journey to the airport count as only 2 zones for me?

Gosforth is on the zone 1/2 border and it is technically possible to change trains there, which would give us 2 zones, however the more common route that people take is via Monument, which should be 3 zones.

Am I correct in this?

Under what rationale is it cheaper for someone to reach the airport from this distance rather than for instance the considerably closer Ilford Road?

Comment: I've combed the Ts & Cs and it doesn't seem to make it clear - I think the only ways to find out would be to ask, or just to try it out in person. It wouldn't surprise me if it only charged you for two zones though.

Comment: As for the rationale part of the question, the "central" zone of most transit systems is usually the busiest. Travel that doesn't go through it ("orbital" routes) is often incentivised. If they didn't want to incentivise it they would probably have put the airport in a zone of its own.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The journey will be in two zones After putting the information in the [Live Travel Map](https://livemap.nexus.org.uk/#/liveDepartures) it comes up with a fare of £2.50, valid for both journeys:

> [image]

Looking at the ticket prices, this is in two zones. Note: this applies to PAYG.

Comment: Brilliant, I didn't guess the travel map would show fares! However, it's perhaps worth pointing out that this applies to PAYG --- the conditions for season tickets make it quite clear that seasons must be valid for all zones within which you're travelling. I don't know if the "checkies" tend to board trains or just form blockades at stations, so how likely you are to be caught out on this I'm not sure.